# How to change folder icons with Python on windows, linux, unix, mac …?

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, unix

I would like to write a general method for all operating systems (Win, MacOS, Unix, ...) that changes a folder's icon.

I would like to extend the following implementation

```
import os
import warnings
import ctypes
from ctypes import POINTER, Structure, c_wchar, c_int, sizeof, byref
from ctypes.wintypes import BYTE, WORD, DWORD, LPWSTR, LPSTR
import win32api    

class SetFolderIcon(object):
    def __init__(self, folderPath, iconPath, reset=False):
        assert os.path.isdir(folderPath), "folderPath '%s' is not a valid folder"%folderPath
        self.__folderPath = unicode(os.path.abspath(folderPath), 'mbcs')
        assert os.path.isfile(iconPath), "iconPath '%s' does not exist"%iconPath
        self.__iconPath = unicode(os.path.abspath(iconPath), 'mbcs')
        assert isinstance(reset, bool), "reset must be boolean"
        self.__reset = reset
        # set icon if system is windows
        if os.name == 'nt':
            try:
                self.__set_icon_on_windows()
            except Exception as e:
                warnings.warn("Unable to set folder icon (%s)"%e)
        elif os.name == 'posix':
            raise Exception('posix system not implemented yet')
        elif os.name == 'mac':
            raise Exception('mac system not implemented yet')
        elif os.name == 'os2':
            raise Exception('os2 system not implemented yet')
        elif os.name == 'ce':
            raise Exception('ce system not implemented yet')
        elif os.name == 'java':
            raise Exception('java system not implemented yet')
        elif os.name == 'riscos':
            raise Exception('riscos system not implemented yet')

    def __set_icon_on_windows(self):
        HICON = c_int
        LPTSTR = LPWSTR
        TCHAR = c_wchar
        MAX_PATH = 260
        FCSM_ICONFILE = 0x00000010
        FCS_FORCEWRITE = 0x00000002
        SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000    

        class GUID(Structure):
            _fields_ = [ ('Data1', DWORD),
                         ('Data2', WORD),
                         ('Data3', WORD),
                         ('Data4', BYTE * 8) ]
        class SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS(Structure):
            _fields_ = [ ('dwSize', DWORD),
                         ('dwMask', DWORD),
                         ('pvid', POINTER(GUID)),
                         ('pszWebViewTemplate', LPTSTR),
                         ('cchWebViewTemplate', DWORD),
                         ('pszWebViewTemplateVersion', LPTSTR),
                         ('pszInfoTip', LPTSTR),
                         ('cchInfoTip', DWORD),
                         ('pclsid', POINTER(GUID)),
                         ('dwFlags', DWORD),
                         ('pszIconFile', LPTSTR),
                         ('cchIconFile', DWORD),
                         ('iIconIndex', c_int),
                         ('pszLogo', LPTSTR),
                         ('cchLogo', DWORD) ]
        class SHFILEINFO(Structure):
            _fields_ = [ ('hIcon', HICON),
                         ('iIcon', c_int),
                         ('dwAttributes', DWORD),
                         ('szDisplayName', TCHAR * MAX_PATH),
                         ('szTypeName', TCHAR * 80) ]    

        shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32
        fcs = SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS()
        fcs.dwSize = sizeof(fcs)
        fcs.dwMask = FCSM_ICONFILE
        fcs.pszIconFile = self.__iconPath
        fcs.cchIconFile = 0
        fcs.iIconIndex = self.__reset 
        hr = shell32.SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(byref(fcs), self.__folderPath, FCS_FORCEWRITE)
        if hr:
            raise WindowsError(win32api.FormatMessage(hr))

        sfi = SHFILEINFO()
        hr = shell32.SHGetFileInfoW(self.__folderPath, 0, byref(sfi), sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_ICONLOCATION)
        #if hr == 0:
        #    raise WindowsError(win32api.FormatMessage(hr))

        index = shell32.Shell_GetCachedImageIndexW(sfi.szDisplayName, sfi.iIcon, 0)
        shell32.SHUpdateImageW(sfi.szDisplayName, sfi.iIcon, 0, index)


iconPath = 'C:\\Users\\myself\\Desktop\\icon.ico'
#iconPath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\SHELL32.dll"
SetFolderIcon('C:\\Users\\myself\\Desktop\\Newfolder',iconPath, reset=False)
# reset icon
SetFolderIcon('C:\\Users\\myself\\Desktop\\Newfolder',iconPath, reset=True)
```

As you can see I only implemented the windows version using __set_icon_on_windows method. similar methods such as __set_icon_on_mac ... must be implemented

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `ctypes.cdll`, `ctypes.windll`, or `ctypes.oledll` in a Python library. These loaders cache loaded DLLs, which cache function pointers, including their `argtypes`, `restype`, and `errcheck` prototypes, which is potentially in conflict with other libraries. For a function that returns `HRESULT` use, for example, `shell32 = OleDLL('shell32')`. This handles raising an exception for you in case of an error return value. Otherwise there's no need to use the `win32api` module; just use `raise ctypes.WinError(errcode)`.

Comment: From a filesystem perspective, directories (a.k.a. folders) don't have icons. The icons you see come from a graphical filemanager (like MS Windows' Explorer above) and not really from the underlying OS! So, your switch over the different OSs only works on the few OSs that have a default and where that default is used. BTW: Why do you use a class when a function would do exactly the right thing? Anyhow, you are not asking a question, which makes it hard to actuall answer...

Comment: A method will do that's right, but i used a class to structure the code a bit and put all the needed methods in a class.

Comment: For that, Python has modules. Also, a free function isn't usually called method, only when it is a member of a class.